# Brand new to Blender. Should I download 2.79 or 2.8 beta?

Tags: versions

I am unsure which version to download. If the interface is different in 2.8 then there does not seem any point in using 2.79?

Any advice welcome

thank you

Comment: 2.79 is more stable and better documented, and there are more totorials. The functionality it 2.8 is the same but a different interface.

Comment: I think now the 2.8 is stable enough to work with it, so if you use it you won't have to learn a new interface when it will be released officially.

Comment: thanks for the replies

Answer (score 2):

Blender 2.80 is a beta version, under heavy development (there are still 1121 bugs as I'm writing: https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/project/2/type/Bug/). It is a major version, with a lot of changes in the workflow.

Therefore, as of now, 2.79 is more suitable for projects as it has more documentation and is way more stable.

If you are simply willing to explorer Blender, to learn it, and are ready to accept random crashes or occasional unexpected behaviour, you can go for 2.80.

If you are also new to CG, you should go for 2.79 but have a play with 2.80 to get ready for a future transition.

Comment: Thank you very much